# Set seekp() at the begining of line in file

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to replace a line in the same file i.e to re-write the file. Currently, its writing the line below the line to be changed. I am using **seekp()** to locate the position where the replaced line has to be written. Following is the code snippet.

```
std::fstream file (file_path, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);

 while (getline (file, line)){

pos = file.tellp();

file.seekp(pos, std::ios_base::beg);

// calls another function which find some variables in line, change them and return String 

const char *c = strdup(line.c_str());

file.write(c,line.length());
}
```

Everything is working fine .. The only problem is that its writing the new *line* in file under the original line. Probably its the problem with setting the *tellp()* and *seekp()*. Is there any way by which I can set them to the begining of line to replace the original line with the new onE ?

Thanks !

Comment: You are getting the current pos and one line later setting the file pos to that same pos. Why? Don't you think you should first get the pos, then getline, then seekp?

Comment: You're seeking to the position where you already are, i.e. immediately after the line you just read. You'll need to keep track of the position *before* you read that line.

Comment: You are leaking the strdup-ped string.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? There is a loop - what for? Which line do you want to replace? And why do you want to rewrite the content that is already in the file?

Comment: So I have a file with a lot of lines of varying lenghts and I have to go line by line and search for some words. If that word is found in that line I have to change that word with some other word and write it back to the same file. So far I can traverse through line by line.. find and replace it but when it comes to write it back on the same position where the original word was. It just write the word to the next line and on the same. I tried _pos->getline->seekp()_ but its not working.

Comment: I know .. I have to keep track of the previous position .. But how can I do that in such situation ? :(